# How to use any specific runner from the list in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ci.yml

I have a list of specific gitlab runners. I want to create a ci script, which would pick one of them to run.

GitLab docs only tells how to run job with [both tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#tags), bot not with one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used a variable for a runner.

So my config looks like this:

```yaml
variables:
    TAG_RUNNER: runner_one

include:
  - project: 'gitlab_configs'
    file: '/reusable_script.yml'


stages:
    - job
```

*reusable_script.yml*:

```yaml
job:
    stage: job
    script:
        - script.sh
    tags:
      - $TAG_RUNNER
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think it s
like

```
jobname:
  tags:
   - shell_runner
```